# input datetime não mostra calendário

Tags: html

Tenho o meu `input` `datetime` desta forma:

```
<li>
<label for="DataQueda">Data/Hora Registo</label>
<input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="DataQueda" name="DataQueda" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");?>">
</li>
```

Fica desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas pretendia ter esta opção em caso de alterar a data:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Experimentou separar a data e a hora em campos diferentes? Testou se a saída da data está sendo feita corretamente peloPHP? Dependendo do browser o datetiime separa data e hora em campos, mas note que isso varia de implementação para implementação. Importante [edit] o post e fornecer um [mcve] do problema e descrever melhor como testou, lembrando que o Stack Overflow aceita trechos "executáveis" de HTML

Comment: Ou separa como o Bacco disse pois a maioria dos navegadores tem isso, ou teria que usar/criar um picker para isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se é totalmente válido para vc mas vc pode trocar o `type` de `datetime` para `datetime-local`, a diferença entre eles é que um tem a opção de declarar o fuso horário e o outro não.

- `datetime`: HTML5 Um controle para inserir data e horário (hora, minuto, segundo e fração de segundo) baseado no fuso horário UTC.
- `datetime-local`: HTML5 Um controle para inserir data e horário, sem fuso horário.

O type `datetime`, não mostro o calendário em nenhum browser, mesmo no Chrome, já o `datetime-local` abre o calendário no Chrome, mas não tem a opção do fuso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Veja como Fica no Chrome e no FireFox

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teste vc mesmo

```html
Date / Datetime / Datetime-local<br>
<input type="date" name="" id="">
<input type="datetime" name="" id="">
<input type="datetime-local" name="" id="">
```